# OpenAL: How to use linear attenuation?

Tags: c++, openal

I want to control the way how the sound source volume fades out by distance, how can i do this?

**Edit:** I would also like to know how to scale the sound coordinate system accordingly: i dont want to hear some sound VERY far away from the source: now i would have to change my rendering code to scale coordinates to make it work as i want.

**Edit2:** Although, one solution could be to multiply my coordinates before i send them... but are there more elegant ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That'll be `alDistanceModel(AL_LINEAR_DISTANCE)` or better `alDistanceModel(AL_LINEAR_DISTANCE_CLAMPED)`, which will turn distant sources off entirely.

Read chapters 3.4.3 and 3.4.4 [here](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Documentation/OpenAL%201.1%20Specification.pdf). You also have to set the parameters in the formulas listed there (`AL_MAX_DISTANCE` and `AL_REFERENCE_DISTANCE`) for each source (`alSourcef`).

If the parameters don't make sense, attenuation is turned off. If the sound is stereo, likewise (stereo is just that... stereo -- only mono sounds are 3D).