# OpenAL source sound is not changing even when I change the position

Tags: c++, audio, openal

I'm trying to implement spatial sound with openal, however no matter how much I change the position of the source, the volume of the sound does not change. Here's some sample code:

```
#include <chrono>

#include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alc.h>
#include "stb_vorbis.c"


double timeDiff(std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start, std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point stop) {
  auto dur = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(stop - start);
  return dur.count();
}

int main(void) {
  auto audioDevice = alcOpenDevice(nullptr);
  auto alContext = alcCreateContext(audioDevice, nullptr);

  alcMakeContextCurrent(alContext);
  alDistanceModel(AL_LINEAR_DISTANCE_CLAMPED);
  
  ALuint source = 0;
  alGenSources(1, &source);
  alSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_RELATIVE, AL_TRUE);

  // Added max distance and reference distance, thanks to paddy's comment
  alSourcef(source, AL_MAX_DISTANCE, 50.f);
  alSourcef(source, AL_REFERENCE_DISTANCE, 5.f);

  ALuint buffer = 0;
  alGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
  {

    int spacialAudioChannels = 0, sampleRate = 0;
    short* hData = nullptr;
    int samples = stb_vorbis_decode_filename("Cipher2.ogg", &spacialAudioChannels, &sampleRate, &hData);
    if (hData == nullptr) {
      printf("Failed to open file Cipher2.ogg");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    auto alFormat = spacialAudioChannels == 1 ? AL_FORMAT_MONO16 : AL_FORMAT_STEREO16;
    alBufferData(buffer, alFormat, hData, samples * sizeof(short), sampleRate);

    free(hData);
  }
  
  alSourcei(source, AL_BUFFER, buffer);
  alSourcePlay(source);
  
  auto startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

  while (timeDiff(startTime, std::chrono::steady_clock::now()) < 180.0) {
    double percentElasped = timeDiff(startTime, std::chrono::steady_clock::now()) / 180.0;

    float pos[] = { percentElasped * 100.f, 0.f, 0.f };
    alSourcefv(source, AL_POSITION, pos);
  }
}
```

I'm using stb vorbis to load the ogg file. Then I'm calculating the percent of time that has elasped and finally I'm setting the source postion to that percent.
This should create the effect of the source moving away from the listener and make the sound quieter as time goes on. The problem is that the sounds volume remains the same.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://openal.org/documentation/OpenAL_Programmers_Guide.pdf), or seen [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5782452)? If you don't provide reference information on how much the sound should be attenuated over a specific distance, then the library will not attenuate it at all.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the max distance and reference distance, however the sound still remains the same. Give me a second to update the question

Comment: Have you considered testing this with a shorter sound sample? Your loop is configured to attenuate over a duration of 3 minutes. How long is the audio clip? While experimenting, I would personally choose a shorter interval, such as 5 seconds.

Comment: The audio clip is 3 minutes. I've considered it, but even if I set my pos to { 10000.f, 0.f, 0.f } where I shouldn't be able to hear the sound,, the sound remains the same. I feel like there is some flag that I haven't set that has the 3D sound disabled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded and installed the latest OpenAL SDK (Windows) and copied your code. Instead of messing around with audio files, I generated a 5-second mono 440Hz waveform. This worked correctly.

So, I decided to try stereo, and found that it did not attenuate at all. On reading the [documentation](http://openal.org/documentation/OpenAL_Programmers_Guide.pdf) for `alBufferData`, I see the following comment in the Remarks section:

> Buffers containing more than one channel of data
> will be played without 3D spatialization.

I would say this is probably the crux of your issue. It's likely that you have a stereo audio file. Try converting it to mono.

Here is my test program which moves the audio source from far-left to far-right:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

#include "al.h"
#include "alc.h"

template <typename T, typename TimePoint>
T timeDiff(TimePoint start, TimePoint stop)
{
    auto dur = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<T>>(stop - start);
    return dur.count();
}

std::vector<short> generateWave(int sampleRate, float durationSeconds, float frequencyHz, bool stereo)
{
    std::vector<short> samples;
    int numChannels = stereo + 1;
    int numSamples = static_cast<int>(sampleRate * durationSeconds) * numChannels;
    samples.reserve(numSamples);
    for (int t = 0; t < numSamples; t++)
    {
        double amplitude = sin(3.1415927 * 2.0 * frequencyHz * t / sampleRate / numChannels);
        samples.push_back(static_cast<short>(amplitude * 32767));
    }
    return samples;
}

int main()
{
    using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;

    const bool stereo = false;
    const int sampleRate = 44100;
    const float waveFrequencyHz = 440.f;
    const float playTimeSeconds = 5.f;
    const float maxDistance = 50.f;
    const float refDistance = 5.f;

    // Init device context
    auto audioDevice = alcOpenDevice(nullptr);
    auto alContext = alcCreateContext(audioDevice, nullptr);
    alcMakeContextCurrent(alContext);
    alDistanceModel(AL_LINEAR_DISTANCE_CLAMPED);

    // Create audio source
    ALuint source = 0;
    alGenSources(1, &source);
    alSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_RELATIVE, AL_TRUE);

    // Added max distance and reference distance, thanks to paddy's comment
    alSourcef(source, AL_MAX_DISTANCE, maxDistance);
    alSourcef(source, AL_REFERENCE_DISTANCE, refDistance);

    // Create audio buffer
    ALuint buffer = 0;
    alGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    std::vector<short> samples = generateWave(sampleRate, playTimeSeconds, waveFrequencyHz, stereo);
    alBufferData(buffer, stereo ? AL_FORMAT_STEREO16 : AL_FORMAT_MONO16, samples.data(), (ALsizei)samples.size() * sizeof(short), sampleRate);

    // Play audio source
    alSourcei(source, AL_BUFFER, buffer);
    alSourcePlay(source);

    // Animate the audio source from far-left to far-right
    auto startTime = Clock::now();
    for (float elapsed = 0; elapsed < playTimeSeconds; elapsed = timeDiff<float>(startTime, Clock::now()))
    {
        float t = elapsed / playTimeSeconds;
        float x = (t * 2.f - 1.f) * maxDistance;
        float pos[] = { x, 0, refDistance };  // offset z to avoid artifacts transitioning through origin
        alSourcefv(source, AL_POSITION, pos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you the audio started to become quieter. I was almost about to give up on this feature

Comment: This also works for me, if you're on linux, you can easily convert a stereo sound file to mono: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51494497/6660685

Comment: An alternative would be to read the file as stereo and mix it down to mono at runtime without requiring external processing tools. That would be useful if needing to deal with user-supplied audio. But yeah, for built-in application resources, use whatever tool you like to ensure the data is in the correct format to begin with.